# Why when I try to download a free app on my iPad it says Tap Continue and Sign In To View Billing Info?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

Okay so when I try to download a free app from the App Store it says "Tap Continue And Sign In To View Billing Info". I Searched up how to fix it and I found...."select none for the payment type of credit card " and I did that and it does not have that option!yes I have used a credit card on ROBLOX for ROBUX ....PLEASE HELP ME OUT I'm scared that I might mess up my ipad

Comment: Hi Julissa, and welcome to Ask Different! A couple questions that I'd like you to answer so we can help you to best: Have you tried to purchase something from the app store and had the card declined? **~or~** Is this a new device linked to your Apple ID? What version of iOS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when that happens I open iTunes on my desktop to choose "None" as my payment type. Then when I re-visit my billing info on my device the "None" option is selected and I leave it as that. However, some applications or trials for in-app purchases will require you to enter a credit card to use that service, so that's another issue you may run into if you continue to keep the option "None" in your billing info.